# Red Sparrow shower scene

Tags: plot-explanation, red-sparrow

In *Red Sparrow*, when Jennifer Lawrence attacks the couple in the shower with a club, did they die?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; later in the movie her uncle (if I remember correctly) laughed and said she broke the girl’s jaw.