# Was Dominika really that cold-blooded?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, red-sparrow

In "Red Sparrow (2018)", Jennifer Lawrence's character kills two people in cold blood before both the hotel incident and joining the secret agency.

What those people did to her was unforgivable- however, killing them easily and going home with no further thoughts is both chilling and shocking.

Didn't it occur to Dominica that she could be hanged for the murder of two people? Did she have no remorse or regret? Typically, normal people are deeply effected by such actions. 
Dominica, however, just goes on with her life like it's no big deal.

Is there an implication that she was meant for this secret life from the start?

What was the point of that subplot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In "Red Sparrow (2018)", right off the bat Jennifer Lawrence's character kills two people in cold blood.

## Actually, NO, she doesn't

Certainly they are severely injured but we later find out that [**the couple were not killed**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87652/red-sparrow-shower-scene).

> Dominica just goes on to live her life like its no big deal.

**Again, this is not the case**

We see Dominika on the tram/bus seeing the blood on her hands and calling the emergency services from a telephone box to go to the locker room where the attack took place.

Clearly there is some regret or remorse over her actions.

*Unfortunately, your whole question is based on a false premise.*